# EC2 instance - attach ephemeral drives on launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to attach the ephemeral partitions on my ec2 instances using boto.

I have tried that with AWS tools and worked:

`./ec2-run-instances ami-018c9568 
                     --instance-type m2.4xlarge 
                     --availability-zone us-east-1a 
                     -n 1 -k my_keypair -g sg-11111111 
                     -b "/dev/xvdb=ephemeral0" 
                     -b "/dev/xvdc=ephemeral1" 
                     -b "/dev/xvdd=ephemeral2" 
                     -b "/dev/xvde=ephemeral3"`

When I try it with boto it doesn't work:

`mapping = BlockDeviceMapping()
 eph0 = BlockDeviceType()
 eph1 = BlockDeviceType()
 eph2 = BlockDeviceType()
 eph3 = BlockDeviceType()
 eph0.ephemeral_name = 'ephemeral0'
 eph1.ephemeral_name = 'ephemeral1'
 eph2.ephemeral_name = 'ephemeral2'
 eph3.ephemeral_name = 'ephemeral3'
 mapping['/dev/xvdb'] = eph0
 mapping['/dev/xvdc'] = eph1
 mapping['/dev/xvdd'] = eph2
 mapping['/dev/xvde'] = eph3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. I was experimenting with instance type with a single ephemeral (I thought it had two). Hope it helps other people.